# Is the connection string plain text when connecting to Azure?

Tags: azure

When you connect to a Azure Sql Database using the given connection string (which includes a password and username) is the string encrypted especially the username and password? Is it send like an https connection or is it send via plain text (http)?

I can't find documentation about this. I don't want to encrypt the connection string locally because I am the only working on this project and it is not available on GitHub or any other platform.

Comment: you can use azure ad authentication for azure sql then you dont have to use any credentials in the connectionstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview#transport-layer-security-tls-encryption-in-transit) and the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934027/how-secure-is-azure-sql-connection), it uses TLS encrypt connection string.

```
Sql Server enforces encryption (SSL/TLS) at all times for all connections.
```